# Single Sign in MS ACCESS users with two roles and area of responsibilities

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I wrote a code for a single sign in an ms access database.
User logs in the AutoExec macro checks if the User on the PC exists in the list with users in the tblUsers

However, the problem is that that every user has an Area of Responsibility. Couple of user also have a Second Role. I can't get that. I tried with DLOOKUP, however I get an error: ***Data Type mismatch in criteria expression.***

Here is my code for single sign and the way how I do the DLOOKUP:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

'Aufruf: getLogonName

Declare Function GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" _
      Alias "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long


' Main routine to retrieve user name.
Public Function getLogonName() As String
On Error GoTo Err_getLogonName

' Dimension variables
Dim lpBuff As String * 255
Dim ret As Long

' Get the user name minus any trailing spaces found in the name.
ret = GetUserName(lpBuff, 255)

If ret > 0 Then
    getLogonName = Left(lpBuff, InStr(lpBuff, Chr(0)) - 1)
Else
    getLogonName = vbNullString
End If

Exit_getLogonName:

Exit Function

Err_getLogonName:

MsgBox "Single Sign Error: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
Resume Exit_getLogonName

End Function


Public Function Logon()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

'\\ Dimension variables
Dim intUserLevel As Integer
Dim intUser As Integer
Dim intSecondRole As String
Dim intPersonnelArea As Integer


If DCount("[UserID]", "tblUser", "[User Login] = '" & getLogonName & "'") > 0 Then
   MsgBox "Welcome " & getLogonName
Else
   Application.Quit acQuitSaveNone
End If

If (IsNull(DLookup("[User Login]", "tblUser", "[Area of Responsibility] ='" & getLogonName & "'"))) > 0 Then
'intSecondRole = DLookup("[Second Role]", "tblUser", "[Second Role] ='" & getLogonName & "'")
'intPersonnelArea = DLookup("[UserID]", "tblUser", "[Area of Responsibility] ='" & getLogonName & "'")
'If intSecondRole = 1 Then

MsgBox "yes"
Else
MsgBox "No"

End If

intUserLevel = DLookup("[User Security]", "tblUser", "[User Login] ='" & getLogonName & "'")

'\\ Check if the saved User Security "Admin" (1) then open the Administration Navigation Form
If intUserLevel = 1 Then
   DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_AdminNavigationForm"
'\\ Check if the saved User Security "User" (2) then open the User Navigation Form
ElseIf intUserLevel = 2 Then
   DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_UserNavigationForm"
'\\ Check if the saved User Security "Finance" (4) then open the Finance Navigation Form
ElseIf intUserLevel = 4 Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_FinanceNavigationForm"
Else
     MsgBox "Not Authorized", vbCritical, "Entry Denied"
End If

ErrorHandler:
MsgBox "Single Sign Error: " & Err & ": " & Error(Err)

End Function
```

Comment: Data Type mismatch is a very explicit error. It says, in your query (your `DLookup` in this case), in your *criteria expression*, the data type you are passing in is not a valid parameter data type. That being said, what line do you receive the error on? I see multiple DLookups.

Comment: intSecondRole = DLookup("[Second Role]", "tblUser", "[Second Role] ='" & getLogonName & "'")
'intPersonnelArea = DLookup("[UserID]", "tblUser", "[Area of Responsibility] ='" & getLogonName & "'")

Comment: So, `getLogonName` is a function. I don't see a variable that is assigned to the result of `getLogonName`. It seems like you're passing in a function in the `WHERE` clause. I don't think that's how it works. Try `Dim varName as String varName = getLogonName()` then in the immediate window type: `?varName` and see if you get the logon name.

Answer (score 0):

You have a dlookup that assigns the return value to an Integer:

```
intUserLevel = DLookup("[User Security]", "tblUser", "[User Login] ='" & getLogonName & "'")
```

That fails if the dlookup returns Null. Wrap the dlookup in a nz():

```
intUserLevel = nz(DLookup("[User Security]", "tblUser", "[User Login] ='" & getLogonName & "'"),0)
```